# Could not use Observable.of in RxJs 6 and Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs6, angular-observable

```
 import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

// And if I try to return like this
  return Observable.of(this.purposes);
```

I am getting an error stating, Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Comment: In v6 it'd be just `return of(this.purposes)`.

Comment: where is this documented? The typical line is "You pull in any operator you need from one spot, under 'rxjs/operators' " which is obviously different from creation, but it's not clear the static method has been replaced. This import knowledge being scattered across the galaxy like I'm looking for the Tox Uthat is just lost time.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Looks like cartant's comment is correct, the [RxJS upgrade guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) doesn't cover that method specifically but does say *"Classes that operate on observables have been replaced by functions"*

Which seems to mean all or most of those class methods like .of, .throw etc. have been replaced by a function

So instead of

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
Observable.of(this.purposes);
```

do

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
of(this.purposes);
```

Comment: import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

Comment: What about `reduce()`?

Comment: reduce() has been moved to the operators so you can import it using `import {reduce} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: This is such an awful change.  These methods should be static methods on a class like they were before.  Name collisions are much more likely now.

Comment: You can have an overview of changes https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: of is now deprecated, documentation advises to use scheduled instead

Answer (score 4):

rxjs 6

```
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class SelectivePreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
       return route.data && route.data.preload === false ? of(null) : load();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid [black-list linting of the rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697345/what-is-the-tslint-blacklist-and-why-does-angular-cli-default-rxjs-on-the-list-i), import them like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```