# How to import rxjs timer in angular 6?

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs6

I tried importing rxjs timer on my angular 6 project like

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
```

I also tried it like,

```
Rx.Observable.timer(200, 100)
```

They don't work

Here is the code on [plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8rehy?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Hey @anonymous, Your answer is correct, but its for RxJs version 5

Comment: Hey md-5h0413 the question was asked and the answer was accepted two years ago and you are commenting now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From rxjs 6 (as used in angular 6 project), The general rule is as follows:

- rxjs: Creation methods, types, schedulers and utilities

  ```js
  import { timer, Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from,
           interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
  ```
- rxjs/operators: All pipeable operators:

  ```js
  import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
  ```

Here is the migration guide: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#observable-classes

Comment: @NitinJadhav when i upgraded to angular 6 / rxjs 6+ i had to manually update tslint.json > import-blacklist section and removed "rxjs". It makes sense to do so as this only applied to previous versions of rxjs

Answer (score 19):

All observable classes (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/5.5.8/src/observable) have been removed from v6, in favor of existing or new operators that perform the same operations as the class methods.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { timeInterval, pluck, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

var sourcef = timer(200, 100)
  .pipe(
    timeInterval(),
    pluck('interval'),
    take(3)
  )
```

**[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwm3gu?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)**

See also

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#observable-classes

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756602/passing-data-all-the-way-from-childa-component-to-its-parent-component-and-then

Answer (score 4):

as of rxjs 6.2.2, for this import

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';   // gives tslint blacklisted error
```

tslint gives an error:

```
ERR: [tslint] This import is blacklisted, 
import a submodule instead (import-blacklist)
```

**but this works fine without any error**

`import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';   //works fine`

Comment: Do you know why import directly from rxjs is restricted? Just curious.

Comment: @SiddhantSwami AIAIK because importing directly from rxjs was causing import of the whole bundle which is really large. Angular can tree shake code when you import from 'rxjs/observable/timer' resulting in reduced bundle size.

Comment: import from rxjs is the right way forwards. If you migrated from a previous version of angular you would have to manually update tslint >  import-blacklist section to remove this part. You can verify this by downloading latest version of @angular/cli,  produce a new angular application and check import-blacklist defaults

Comment: @SiddhantSwami here there is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697345/what-is-the-tslint-blacklist-and-why-does-angular-cli-default-rxjs-on-the-list-i

Comment: I had to do an import fom `rxjs/internal/observable/timer` (RXJS v6.1.0)

Answer (score -1):

In my case I used import { timer } from 'rxjs/Observable/timer'; like this.

but need to use in import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer'; Observable instead of observable.

that's all... enjoy your coding.