# Passing data all the way from childA component to its parent component and then to childB component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and it has two child ,
1.app-search-list and
2.app-vertical-menu

I am passing data from app-search-list(childA) component to its parent component and then from parent to the app-vertical-menu component(childB) as shown in the image
[image]

You can find the link to the code on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-n9pmlg-qfxbac?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Passing data in this way is working fine but if we go to any other routes
and come back and click the list from the select list component , The data is not passing as expected.
I have made a video to explain the problem. Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7tcyPNKJ90) to it

Comment: You should consider to us ngrx statemanagement

Comment: We have already started building this app, a year ago.

Comment: That doesn't change the general best practice to use redux patterns for complex applications. The problem now is caused by this design decision.

Comment: Then you need a service which is injected by every componenent

Comment: true but dont want to do it with a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when a group is already selected it will only update to the child component (`vertical-menu.component`) when the reference to the value has changed in the parent (`app.component`).  So if you click a Group that is already selected nothing will occur because it will reference the same object.  This is due to change detection in angular.

One solution is to simply create a new instance of the object being emitted from `search-list.component`.

#### search-list.component.ts

```
public onClickList(list:any) {
  const selected = Object.assign({}, list);
  this.selectedList.emit(selected);
}
```

Linked below is a forked stackblitz of what I think you're trying to accomplish.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-n9pmlg-6fds9q
>
> https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7

Comment: Thanks it works but I also want to remove the active class of the selected list

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a setter to pass value to your childB? something like this:

```
data: any

@Input()
  set selectedData(selectedData: any) {
    if (!!selectedData) {
      this.data = selectedData;
    }
  }
```