# Deprecated methods in rxjs v6

Tags: angular, rxjs, tslint

I try to use `combineLatest`:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

but I get the warning

```
combineLatest is deprecated: Deprecated in favor of static combineLatest.
```

If I follow [the solution provided in the RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#dep-methods) as it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276165/combinelatest-deprecated-in-favor-of-static-combinelatest) and I write

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

then I get the tslint message:

```
This import is blacklisted, import a submodule instead
```

which seems a bit a snake biting its own tail...

If I use

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/combineLatest';
```

then it works without warning messages, but as far as I know, it's not recommended to import internal packages (correct me if I'm wrong).

Disabling tslint messages doesn't seem acceptable to me.

Example:

```
this.Subscription = combineLatest([a,b])
    .pipe(
      map( (...) )
    ).subscribe( (...) );
```

Which is the appropriate solution? Thanks.

Comment: show us your code (where you use the function ) and the rxjs version  plz

Comment: I think it could help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274275/angular-6-ng-lint-combinelatest-is-deprecated

Comment: The link I provided showed that the rxjs version is v6 but since it was too hidden I made it explicit. I added a very simple example. The other stackoverflow question doesn't solve my problem and the second solution produces precisely one of the tslint messages I mentioned. :-(

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting lint rules. And you should never use internal import locations.

Comment: Only me? Isn't it happening to anyone using rxjs?

Comment: It looks like you have an older Angular project and you're trying to use it with newer RxJS. In Angular (or angular-cli aka ng) importing directly from `rxjs` was blacklisted. This is however not an issue in newer angular-cli and rxjs that supports import maps.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by and older Angular project: I have angular (7.2.15), tslint (5.16.0) and rxjs (6.5.2) updated to the latest versions, but the problem is still there. What should I still update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution, based on @martin's comment: my original project was created using Angular 6. When I upgraded Angular 6 to Angular 7 I didn't take into account that `tslint.json`had been updated. This file was simplified and it included the line

`"extends": "tslint:recommended"`

([See here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6179) for more details). In the recommended tslint file, the package `rxjs` had been excluded from the blacklist.

So, I had an old version of the file `tslint.json`, I updated it and now I don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/index';` to avoid deprecated library or  blacklisted lint.

See this: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the sanctioned by the official documentation way of importing `combineLatest`, tslint is just being silly here.

Edit your `tslint.json` and remove `rxjs` the `"import-blacklist"` entry.

Comment: Importing all `rxjs` is deprecated because it's a huge package. I think it makes sense to import only the pieces you need...

Comment: `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'` isn't "importing all `rxjs`", it's exactly that: import only the pieces you need.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I meant is the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697345/what-is-the-tslint-blacklist-and-why-does-angular-cli-default-rxjs-on-the-list-i . But this is quite contradictory with https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/585 which, by the way, is already closed and it's not being changed. Why???